# Implement a reversible iteration class to replace a generator

Tags: python, iterator, generator

In python, I have a class with a method that returns a generator:

```
class foo():
    data = [1, 2, 3]
    def mygen(self):
        for d in self.data:
            yield d

instance = foo()
print([i for i in instance.mygen()])
```

But I can't reverse this:

```
print([i for i in reversed(instance.mygen())])
TypeError: 'generator' object is not reversible
```

So I thought I could implement a class which returns a generator when calling `__iter__`, like this

```
class foo():
    data = [1, 2, 3]
    def mygen(self):
        return _ReversibleIterator(self)

class _ReversibleIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __iter__(self):
        for d in obj.data:
            yield d

    def __reversed__(self):
        for d in reversed(obj.data):
            yield d
```

But I think this isn't quite the same, because the `_ReversibleIterator` class doesn't have a `next()` method.

So what is the pythonic way to create a class method that returns an iterator that can be `reversed()`?

(Obviously I'm just using `[1,2,3]` as an example. The real thing to iterate over is less trivially reversible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), `reversed` must have one of two things to work with: a `__reversed__` method OR a `__len__` and a `__getitem__` method. If you think about it, this makes sense because most generators *can't* support `reversed` because they generate results on the fly: they don't know what the next, let alone the last element is going to be. However, if you know its length and have random-access to any index, it can be reversed.

```
class foo():
    data = [1, 2, 3]
    def mygen(self):
        return _ReversibleIterator(self)

class _ReversibleIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def __reversed__(self):
        return reversed(self.obj.data)

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            el = self.obj.data[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index += 1
        return el
```

or

```
class _ReversibleIterator(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        self.index = 0
        return self

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.obj.data)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.obj.data[i]

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            el = self[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index += 1
        return el
```

By the way, if you would like, you can replace `for d in whatever: yield d` with `yield from whatever`.

Comment: Thanks! (I just edited the question to add a `__reversed__` methods, which I previously forgot). But even with those methods, the returned object is not *quite* the same, because it doesn't have a `next()` method. In the simple generator case, I can do `a = instance.mygen(); print(next(a))`, but when I return a `_ReversibleIterator`, `next` produces an error: TypeError: '_ReversibleIterator' object is not an iterator.

Comment: @user2667066 Usually, iterators implement the actual generation part in a `__next__` method, and all `__iter__` does is return `self`. I can make an edit.

Comment: Thanks, that would be useful. But does that mean I can't simply use a generator in the `__iter__` part?

Comment: @user2667066 You could, but then you wouldn't have `__next__`. Also, may I ask if you have the ability to implement `__len__` and `__getitem__` for your use case?

Comment: @user2667066 By the way, if you *really* wanted `next` functionality, you don't need to add anything to your class if you change `a = instance.mygen()` to `a = iter(instance.mygen())`. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @iz : in one of my use cases I can definitely implement `__len__` and `__getitem__`, yes. But I presume that still doesn't help with `__next__`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197961/discussion-between-iz-and-user2667066).

Comment: This is useful, thanks. It's a shame that we need to keep counters etc, and there aren't built-in python wrappers for this sort of thing to reduce the verbosity.